# how to check which player only has one team sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I am a beginner with sql and I am stuck with the problem that I don't know how to check which players have more than one team or not.

after making a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM(TeamID varchar(10), 
                  PlayerID varchar(10) REFERENCES "Player" ("playerID"),
                  TeamName varchar(15));
```

And then the values:

```
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ('t001', 'p001','teamname1');

INSERT INTO Team VALUES ('t001', 'p002','teamname1');

INSERT INTO Team VALUES ('t002', 'p003','teamname2');

INSERT INTO Team VALUES ('t002', 'p002','teamname2');
```

As you can see: player 2 has more teams and others only have one team. But how do I write that it is possible to look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count using the following query:

```
Select playerId,count(TeamId) from TEAM group by playerId having count(teamId)>=1
```

Comment: maybe my sqlite works different so after changing the first one to playerID from Team(otherwise there will be an error), there is an syntax error near from for some reason edit: fixed! all of these answers here are great and thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(PlayerId)
from Team 
where PlayerId = 'some Id';
```

This will return the count of teams where the player participates.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions depending on what you want exactly

List of all all players within teams and the number of teams they are in

```
Select playerId,count(*) 
from TEAM 
group by playerId 
ORDER BY count(*) DESc

| PlayerID | count(*) |
|----------|----------|
|     p002 |        2 |
|     p001 |        1 |
|     p003 |        1 |
```

Only players within several teams

```
SELEcT playerId,count(*) 
FROM TEAM 
GROUP BY playerId 
HAvING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESc

| PlayerID | count(*) |
|----------|----------|
|     p002 |        2 |
```

Players within teams, and the teams they are in

```
SELEcT playerId,count(*) , GROUP_concat(Teamname) AS teams
FROM TEAM 
GROUP BY playerId 
ORDER BY count(*) DESc

| PlayerID | count(*) |               teams |
|----------|----------|---------------------|
|     p002 |        2 | teamname1,teamname2 |
|     p001 |        1 |           teamname1 |
|     p003 |        1 |           teamname2 |
```

Additionally, if you need all players even if they arent in a team, you should make the same query but with `FROM Players LEFT JOIN Teams` which I won't covert  more as you did not shown your player table